how to obtain optimal random survival forest
I have a question. When performing random survival forest (RSF), how to obtain optimal RSF? My idea is to screen variables using variable importance (VIMP), then tune model parameters: ntree, nodesize and nsplit.
i am not sure whether the functions tune.nodesize and tune.rfsrc can meet the requirement for the second step.
The codes for the first step are as follows,
`library(randomForestSRC)
data(peakVO2, package = "randomForestSRC")
dta <- peakVO2
obj <- rfsrc(Surv(ttodead,died)~., dta,
ntree = 1000, nodesize = 5, nsplit = 50, importance = TRUE)
jk.obj <- subsample(obj)
plot(jk.obj)`

Positive VIMP indicates variables is helpfu to predict survival time/event while zero or negative values identify noise variables. As a result, we only keep the variable with positive VIMP.
Is my strategy right? Thanks in advance.
